# Mvc3 Adding user roles in tightly bound dropdownbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a register model thats tighly bound to a register view. The register model has a selectlistitem poperty. Im having trouble populating a dropdownbox with the select list items.

```
var users = Roles.GetAllRoles();

model.UserRoles = users.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
{Value = m.ToString(),Text = m.ToString()})

@Html.DropDownListFor(r=>r.ToString(),Model.UserRoles,"Select Role")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the selected value to a property of your model, like so:

(in your Model):

```
public string ActiveRole { get; set; }
```

...

(in your View):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ActiveRole, Model.UserRoles,"Select Role")
```

Comment: What I did was bind it to a name property in my model. Thanks

Comment: Now i really understand what ure saying.lol, i learnt the hard way. I was trying to get a selected value. I created a property "selected role" thats bound to the drop down.. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of the `DropDownListFor` method is the property which holds the value of the list. If the value in the list will be the id of the role this has to have the argument `x => x.RoleId` where `x` is your model and `RoleId` is the property in the model. You are binding the dropdownlist to the string representation of the viewmodel, the result of which is garbage.

The second argument is an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` which holds the options for the list. This object has the following values: `Value` is the value that is send back to the server, this should be what identifies the role, often the id of the role. `Text` is the text that is displayed in the list, it is what the user sees. `Selected` is a boolean that indicates which item in the list is selected. If it is false in all of the `SelectListItem`s, the top one is selected, which is standard HTML behaviour.

In your case, you are placing the `SelectListItem`s in the model, which is an unnecessary step, but should work. The model binder won't understand the first argument though, so you need to fix that one.